# iPhone 5 code migration

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5, iphone-5

I have an application written for iPhone 4s screen resolution and below. Now I would like to migrate it to iPhone 5 screen resolution. I read a lot of answers online and I am pretty much clear with the procedure now.

What I would like to know is whether I need to have the latest version of Xcode to perform this migration. As far as I can see I can do all of the procedures using Xcode 4.2 itself, but most of the answers suggested I need to download the latest Xcode. If its really needed, Please let me know the reason behind this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you will need iOS 6 SDK, so any version of Xcode that supplied with the iOS 6 SDK will do.

As of the now, Apple will not even accept any apps that are not compatible with the 4" screen. meaning that you will need to use the iOS 6 SDK.

Comment: Thanks @rckoenes. But I still did not get the reason behind this. If it is just about adding the Default@2x-586h.png file, I can do it with XCode 4.2 itself right?

Comment: No, since only the iOS 6.0 SDK support the 4" iOS devices. Apple does not allow you to submit any apps that have a lower SDK than 6.0 and have the `Default@2x-586h.png`. You can still target iOS 4.3 with the latest iOS SDK.

Comment: Ok. That answers the whole of my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need XCode 4.5 (iOS SDK 6) or up to be able to support iPhone 5.
This is because of the fact that the iPhone 5 support is realised by adding a Default@2x-586h.png launch image to the application project. Only XCode 4.5/iOS SDK 6 and up will detect this file and enable iPhone 5 support properly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to design your screen.

Simple solution is just add a Default@2x-586h.png in the bundle's root folder, and when the app runs in iPhone 5, it will try to run in full screen mode.

I think this is possible even in xcode 4.2. And, in worst case, you may need to design all your UIViews programmatically. I did not try it myself, since I am using latest xcode, but if you have old xcode, you can give it a try. For one of my app, when I this png file, all the screens accomodate itself well with iPhone 5 screen.

But if you want to have all the advanced features like autolayout and design your screen with xib or storyboard, then you need the latest xcode and sdks. Requirements for,

Storyboard -> iOS 5 sdk and Xcode 4.2

Autolayout -> iOS 6 sdk and Xcode 4.5

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the following statement - "This can be done even in xcode 4.2. And, in this case, you may need to design all your UIViews programmatically". I did not quite get why I need to do design all my views programatically if I use Xcode 4.2.

Comment: If you have usual UIView in a view controller and set that view as self.view, usually it have the property set as auto resize in height and width and works fine for iPhone5. But if you design more than one UIViews in a xib file, you may need to design UIViews in separate xib files for iPhone 4 (320x480), iPhone 5 (320x568) and also for iPads (768x1024), if you support it. Sometimes it is preferable to design simple views in loadView() method rather having 3 xib/storyboard files. It is also a maintenance hazard.

Answer (score 0):

Starting May 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store **must be** built for iOS devices with Retina display and **iPhone apps must also support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5**. Learn about preparing your apps by reviewing the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

[Apple: News And Announcements](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=3212013b)